# Optimizing Database Queries in Django With Categories and Subcategories

Tags: python, django, optimization, query-optimization

The following function gets all categories and subcategories and then passes them to a template. Basically the topcategory has `category id = 1` -- so we get any categories that have the top category as their parent, and then we get their subcategories. The problem is that we have ~90 queries based on this code. I'm wondering if someone could suggest a more efficient way of rendering this information and cutting down the number of database calls?

```
def all_models(request):
    topcats = Category.objects.filter(parent=1).order_by('category')
    subcats = {}
    for each in topcats:
        subcats [each] = []
        subcategories = Category.objects.filter (parent= each.id).order_by('category')
        for subcat in subcategories:
            subcats[each].append(subcat)
    return render_to_response("parts/all.html", {
        "topcats":topcats,
        "subcats": subcats,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Query for all categories, iterate over them and build the category tree in your code.

Comment: Could you post some code -- I tried something but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
topcats = Category.objects.prefetch_related('category_set').filter(parent_id=1).order_by('category')
```

If you specified a `related_name` for `parent` in your model, you should of course replace `category_set` with that name.

This will fetch all needed categories in just two queries. You might want to define ordering on your model itself, or you won't be able to order by `category` on your subcategories. Then, in your template, you can do:

```
{% for topcat in topcats %}
    - {{ topcat.category }}
    {% for subcat in topcat.category_set.all %}
        -- {{ subcat.category }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```